# Change existing XML child value with textbox.text

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, child-nodes

I've been trying to apply `TextBox.Text` values to my existing XML file nodes, I've tried many ways but it doesn't seem to pick up on it.

My code:

```
private void btnAddId_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

   if (tbAddId.Text == "")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("No value was given!");
   }
   else if (tbAddId.Text == "Add ID")
   {
      MessageBox.Show("No value was given!");
   }
   else
   {
      XmlDocument Xdoc = new XmlDocument();
      string xmldoc = (@"// path to my xml file");
      Xdoc.Load(xmldoc);


      XmlElement elList = (XmlElement)Xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/filter/filter_item");

      if (elList != null)
      {
         XmlNode node = Xdoc.SelectSingleNode("filter_item");
         node.InnerText = tbAddId.Text;
         elList.AppendChild(node);
      }

      Xdoc.Save(xmldoc);

   }

}
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <filter>
    <!-- Copy filter-item and put the order-id in as the value to skip it-->
    <filter_item>
    </filter_item>
  </filter>
</root>
```

Does anyone know the best way to add `TextBox.Text` to an existing child node?

Comment: Is `elList` not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `elList` variable is `null`, because you forgot the `root` node in the XPath. If there is only one `filter_item` node, as I guess from your usage of `SelectSingleNode`, this should work:

```
XmlDocument Xdoc = new XmlDocument();
string xmldoc = (@"// path to my xml file");
Xdoc.Load(xmldoc);


var filterItemNode = Xdoc.SelectSingleNode("root/filter/filter_item");
if (filterItemNode != null)
   filterItemNode.InnerText = tbAddId.Text;

Xdoc.Save(xmldoc);
```

This will result in the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
   <filter>
      <filter_item>Text from the TextBox</filter_item>
   </filter>
</root>
```